Oracle SQL Developer Multi query consult on one table, to get two results
the query should do this:
Run a query that shows the employee count per manager and the manager's name. Using the same table.
    SELECT
    gerente.nombre_empleado AS Nombre_Gerente,
    COUNT(emp.nombre_empleado) AS Total
FROM
    xxaazl_empleados_t emp 
JOIN xxaazl_empleados_t gerente ON emp.gerente = gerente.gerente
WHERE
    emp.gerente IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    gerente.nombre_empleado;

The result is this:
    Manager_name   Total

  1  María          3
  2  Pedro          3
  3  Laura          3
  4  Elena          2
  5  Jennifer       2

But should be like this:
  Manager_name   Total

1   Carlos           3
2   Juan             2

Here is the table:


How do you expect help when you have not shared the table data?

I just posted it

I don't think you can do that with table you have as it lacks information who is whose manager.
A better table is emp that belongs to Scott's sample schema:
SQL> select * from emp order by mgr nulls first;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500          0         30
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2850                    30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800                    20

14 rows selected.

SQL>

It says that

KING doesn't have a manager (he is the King, after all :))
FORD and SCOTT have the same manager whose "ID" (in this context, that's the EMPNO column stored in the MGR column) is 7566, and 7566 EMPNO belongs to JONES

which means that JONES' count should be equal to 2


at the bottom of the list, BLAKE, JONES and CLARK have a manager whose EMPNO = 7839, and that's KING, so King's count is then 3

Query - that utilizes self-join (as your attempt also shows) - is then
SQL> select m.ename, count(e.empno) cnt
  2  from emp m join emp e on e.mgr = m.empno
  3  group by m.ename;

ENAME             CNT
---------- ----------
JONES               2   --> as we said, Jones has two employees
FORD                1
CLARK               1
SCOTT               1
BLAKE               5
KING                3   --> King has 3 employees

6 rows selected.

SQL>


In your table, there's no such relationship; it lacks in the MGR column (or whatever its name might be). GERENTE column just doesn't seem to be the one (I don't know what it represents).

One option is to select managers first and inner join the rest of employees counting employees by GERENTE column - assuming that GERENTE column for employees is constructed as 'M' || DEPARTAMENTO of the manager.
Create Table EMPLEADOS ( ID_EMPLEADO      Number(6),
                         NOMBRE_EMPLEADO  VarChar2(32),
                         DEPARTAMENTO     VarChar2(32), 
                         PUESTO           VarChar2(32), 
                         GERENTE          VarChar2(16) );

--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Insert Into EMPLEADOS 
( Select 900020, 'Juan',     'TI',  'Manager TI',     Null From Dual Union All 
  Select 900021, 'Maria',    'TI',  Null ,           'MTI' From Dual Union All 
  Select 900022, 'Carlos',   'RH',  'Manager RH',    Null From Dual Union All 
  Select 900023, 'Pedro',    'TI',  'Analista',      'MTI' From Dual Union All 
  Select 900024, 'Laura',    'DEV', 'Desarrollador', 'MTI' From Dual Union All 
  Select 900025, 'Elena',    'RH',  'Reclutador',    'MRH' From Dual Union All 
  Select 900026, 'Jennifer', 'RH',  'Reclutador',    'MRH' From Dual Union All 
  Select 900027, 'John',     Null,  Null,            Null From Dual Union All 
  Select 900028, 'Esteban',  Null,  Null,            Null From Dual )

--     S Q L :
Select     m.NOMBRE_EMPLEADO "MANAGER_NAME",
           Count(e.ID_EMPLEADO)  "TOTAL"
From       EMPLEADOS m
Inner Join EMPLEADOS e ON( e.ID_EMPLEADO != m.ID_EMPLEADO And 
                           e.GERENTE = 'M' || m.DEPARTAMENTO)
Where      m.GERENTE Is Null And 
           m.DEPARTAMENTO Is Not Null
Group By   m.NOMBRE_EMPLEADO
Order By   m.NOMBRE_EMPLEADO

/*      R e s u l t :
MANAGER_NAME    TOTAL
------------    -----
Carlos              2
Juan                3    */

See the fiddle here.
NOTE: This data structure is very unreliable because its integrity could be destroyed by any typo in any column envolved in this sql's join (GERENTE and DEPARTAMENTO).
And the same (even worse) goes for PUESTO column too if we try to do the join using that column instead (the result is the same with the same sample data):
... ...
Inner Join EMPLEADOS e ON( e.ID_EMPLEADO != m.ID_EMPLEADO And 
                           e.GERENTE = Replace(m.PUESTO, 'Manager ', 'M') )
... ...


You can using a single hierarchical query without joins:
SELECT MAX(CONNECT_BY_ROOT nombre_empleado) AS manager,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   xxaazl_empleados_t
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
START WITH puesto = 'Manager ' || departamento
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       'M' || PRIOR departamento = gerente
AND    PRIOR id_empleado != id_empleado
GROUP BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT id_empleado

or maybe START WITH gerente IS NULL (which gives the same output).
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE xxaazl_empleados_t (ID_EMPLEADO, NOMBRE_EMPLEADO, DEPARTAMENTO, PUESTO, GERENTE) AS
  SELECT 900020, 'Juan',     'TI',  'Manager TI',    NULL  FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 900021, 'Maria',    'TI',  NULL,            'MTI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 900022, 'Carlos',   'RH',  'Manager RH',    NULL  FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 900023, 'Pedro',    'TI',  'Analista',      'MTI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 900024, 'Laura',    'DEV', 'Desarrollador', 'MTI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 900025, 'Elena',    'RH',  'Reclutador',    'MRH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 900026, 'Jennifer', 'RH',  'Reclutador',    'MRH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 900027, 'John',     NULL,  NULL,            NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 900028, 'Esteban',  NULL,  NULL,            NULL FROM DUAL

Outputs:



MANAGER
TOTAL




Juan
3


Carlos
2



fiddle
